# How can I export Samsung memos?

Tags: samsung, google-keep, samsung-apps, samsung-galaxy-avant

Using the built-in Memo app on a Samsung Galaxy Avant, I've created several memo files, and they are saved on the device and synced with my Samsung account.  How can I export the memos as text files, or some other readable file format that lets me get the text into another program (e.g. Google Keep)?

Comment: I tried looking in /Android/data/com.samsung.android.app.memo using Android File Transfer, but the only thing there is an empty Cache folder.

Comment: i installed 'samsung notes' app. Then i imported all notes from memo(from settings menu of that app). Then synced it to samsung cloud. This way I didnt have to export them one by one. But the problem is I still cant export the memos as text so that I can import to other apps.https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s6/587633-export-stock-memo-app-data.html

Comment: on a newer version of the samsung notes app, you can export the notes as 'sdoc' files also.

Answer (score 5):

Here, in my opinion, is the best solution for this delemma. I looked everywhere for an answer to no avail. Tried several 3rd party apps for notes, including Evernote, which I didn't like. Get a free Google Drive account if you don't already have one. Then you can go into each Memo, and one by one share your notes (click on three dots) to Google Drive. This goes pretty fast actually. Some Memos you will just want to delete. Google Drive will preserve Memo's formatting (sentence returns) at least, instead of running every line together into one big glob of text (as Evernote will do). And after I did a few of them, it even started saving the Title too, as the name of the note. Now at least you will have access to your notes after you shut your Android down and switch to the iPhone. Then you can copy and paste the most important ones back into your iPhone later — I haven't got to that point yet. I had 95 Memos and was pretty pissed that after all these years, no one at Samsung has figured out how to transfer Memos to an iPhone??? Hope this helps someone.

Comment: At the time of this comment, you can actually just share it straight to google-keep.

Answer (score 4):

*The following applies to Memo app version 1.0.4517634 on Android 4.4.2.*

The memo files are located in `/mnt/shell/emulated/0/BeamMemo` and have a `.memo` extension.

Each `.memo` file is a `zip` archive that contains a `media` folder and a `memo_content.xml` file.  The text of the memo is in the `/contents/content` node of the `xml` document.

I was able to find the files using `adb`, with the command:

```
adb shell 'ls -Ra 2>/dev/null | grep -i memo'
```

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for an option to open .memo files transferred from my android based samsung mobile. Transferring was easy since I had only around 25 notes and did that one by one using the bluetooth facility of mobile and laptop.

After getting the files into pc, opening was an issue. Researched a bit and found that each .memo is basically a .zip file, which contains an .xml file as well as a folder for media. Hence, renamed the extension of these .memo to .zip and then unzipped to obtain these resultant files. Out of this, opened the .xml file to read in readable format the contents of my .memo file. Thanks for sharing the info which helped me solve this.

Comment: this is the best answer thankyou.  copy the files to your desktop, for me there were in phones root in `ShareMemo`  just rename the extension, they are a zip file.  then unzip them.  then open the xml files in notepad++.
The date is in Unix Epoch time, search online for an epoch date converter, paste the string in there, grab the real date, overwrite the xml tags with the date, and keep your original text, then resave the file.  delete the zips after...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your model, Samsung memos usually exist with the following file extensions: `.smm`, `.spd`

They exist in the the following folder: `/storage/emulated/0/.ActionMemo` or `SNote Data` folder

A suitable workaround will be  to convert Samsung memos to a text file or anything similar then extract data as plain text files either from a PC or  do it from the smart phone itself.
The following workarounds can extract the plain text from the memo:

**1. Method 1 Extracting text from memo**

- open the memo that you need to convert and tap it so that you see the cursor.
- click-and-hold the cursor (or somewhere where there is text) and choose Select All.
- click-and-hold on the selected text and choose Copy
- open your word processor (in my case Kingsoft Word) and paste the text.
- Save and then export to Google keep as plain text.

**2. Method 2  Saving by exporting**

- open up your Memos, click on more (top right hand corner on my phone) and then select **share**.
- You then select (one at a time) the memo you want to save/read/open, etc., and a screen will pop up asking you where you want to send the memo.
- You can share to your email, or other sharing options e.g (google drive)
- You can then extract them from mail e.g outlook

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Neither of the folders mentioned exist on the Samsung phones I've checked.  Are there other locations you can recommend checking?