# Export/save 200+ Samsung memos without selecting them one by one?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s7, samsung-apps, export

I would like to save 200+ memo from the default samsung application

### What I did:

I already succedded to save memos one by one but it takes too long to do this for all of them, the process is the following:

- Open the samsung memo application
- Go into each Memo
- Save it by sharing it (thought the three dots) to Google Drive.

### What I wanna do:

- Save all of them without reapeating the steps above 200+ times

*Note: Any ways to save/export them on a more successful way or to use them from another "memo application" are welcome!*

**edit:** I know how to save one memo (as explained above), but I'm looking for a way to automate it or extract a large quantity of them at the same time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to backup notes from stock Notes app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/204402/how-to-backup-notes-from-stock-notes-app)