# Samsung Notes - path for folder for Notes

Tags: samsung-notes

I would like to have an synchronisation with my desktop computer of the folder containing my handwritten Samsung Notes documents. I use Samsung Galaxy Notes S22 Ultra. Where do I find the path containing these documents in the file system of my android phone?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to back up notes from Samsung Notes app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/204402/44325). The answer mentioned several paths.