# Write a script to extract memos?

Tags: applications, scripts

Is it possible to run a script on Android that would access the Samsung memo app, take each note in there, copy its content, send it somewhere (e.g. an email or just store in a text file) then delete the note?

Can something like that be done in Java/C++?

Is it necessary to write an android app for that?  Or is there a way to let a script written in Java, C++ or even Python run on my phone?

By the way, my device is a Samsung S6 and it is unrooted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I export Samsung memos?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/172765/how-can-i-export-samsung-memos)